# Modify Django rest framework request

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

My problem is how to write more strict API using more generic REST API. I have working api in my application but I need to add some more strict services based on generic API and here is a problem because I can't simple override request data because it's immutable. I'm using Django rest framework 3.

Example:

**My generic api for animals:**

```
class AnimalService(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data.copy()
        if data.get('type') == 'dog':
            #...do something
```

Now I need api only for hardcoded dogs:

```
class DogService(AnimalService):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #hardcode request.data['type'] = 'dog'
        return super(DogService, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: A better approach would be to use DRF permission classes and restrict the requests not having `type` as `dog`.

Comment: @RahulGupta yes but I don't need to client send me a type because I can hardcode it in my Dog service. Client don't have to know that I need 'type' in my rest view, so it's impossible to hardcode some arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding the `request` object, you can pass the `type` in `kwargs`. You can then use these `kwargs` in `AnimalServiceView` as these modified `kwargs` are passed to it.

```
class DogService(AnimalService):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['type'] = 'dog' # set the animal type in kwargs
        return super(DogService, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then in your `AnimalService` view, you can do:

```
class AnimalService(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('type') == 'dog': # check the 'type'
            #...do something
```

Another way is to [write a custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) which will set the `animal_type` attribute on the request depending on the requested resource. Then in your views, you can just check using `request.animal_type` attribute.